# Harmonic functions in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I want to establish the equivalence of the 3 standard definitions, and that harmonic functions are $C^\infty$.  The 3 definitions are:

1. Mean value property and continuous.
2. $C^2$ and $0$ Laplacian.
3. Mean value property on arbitrarily small balls and continuous.

The only help I think I need here is proof of the existence and uniqueness of solution for the Dirichlet problem on the ball. (That would help me to get 3 implies 2, along with the maximal property for harmonic functions of type 3, which should be easy to prove.)  2 implies 1 by using arguments to take a derivative under the integral, and then using gauss' divergence theorem.  1 implies 3 obviously.  I also need help seeing that harmonic functions must be $C^\infty$.  I am not used to methods that don't involve complex analysis, as must be used here.

I know that there is a theory of plurisubharmonic functions.  As a bonus question, do those tend to be useful outside of complex analysis, and are they ever discussed for odd dimension?  For example, I have never seen them discussed in harmonic analysis, nor do they seem to be useful in relation to Brownian motions, which is why I am learning the d-dimensional version of harmonic function theory now.

Edit: Come to think of it, I'd also like some help proving the open mapping property and maximal properties for harmonic functions.  Please only assume definition 3 here, because I will use it and a connectedness argument to establish 3 implies 2.  The precise statement of definition 3 is as in Greene and Krantz but for d dimensions:

$f$ is "harmonic (3)" if $f$ is continuous and $\forall x \in U$ the domain of $f$ there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that all balls of radius $\epsilon$ or less centered at $x$ are contained in U, and $f$ satisfies the MVP for that ball/spherical shell.

Comment: That $2 \implies 1 \implies 3$ is obvious: the first from integration by parts, the second by definition. For $3 \implies 2$ see page 17 of [_Harmonic Function Theory_](http://axler.net/HFT.html) by Axler et al, freely available on the author's homepage.

Comment: Also, harmonic analysis is the modern generalisation of Fourier analysis, and _not_ the analysis of harmonic functions, which would be called harmonic function theory and sometimes also studied under the banner of potential theory.

Comment: Oops, if I called it that it was by accident.  Thanks

Comment: Lastly, in relation to Brownian motions, plurisubharmonic functions is probably not the right direction. If you think about how the connection between Brownian motion and harmonic functions are drawn, you would first be lead to the diffusion processes which are tied to solutions of linear elliptic PDEs with variable coefficients, and then to solutions of more general non-linear and non-local partial differential equations. I know that Luis Silvestre and Luis Caffarelli have some interest in this, but I don't know if any of their more accessible presentations are available on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Dirichlet problem on a Ball in $\mathbb R^n$ of radius $r$:

$$\begin{cases}\Delta u=0&\text{ in }B^\circ (0,r)\\u=g&\text{ in }\partial B(0,r)\end{cases}$$ assuming $g$ is continuous on $\partial B(0,r)$.

The Poisson Kernel on this Ball is $$K(x,y)=\dfrac {1}{na(n)r}\cdot\dfrac {r^2-|x|^2}{|x-y|^n}$$ where $a(n)$ is the volume of the unitary ball.

Let $$u(x)=\dfrac{r^2-|x|^2}{na(n)r}\int_{\partial B(0,r)}\dfrac{g(y)}{|x-y|^n}dy, x\in B^\circ (0,r)$$
Then you have to prove that:

$1.u\in C^\infty (B^\circ (0,r))$

$2.\Delta u=0,\text{ in } B^\circ (0,r)$

$3.\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}u(x)=g(x_0),\forall x_0\in\partial B(0,r)$

Comment: Is the kernel that you use here not unique?  It differs from the one suggested in the notes in the comments, as well as what I know for d=2. (by more than just a constant multiple.)  Even if you end up correcting your kernel because of a typo, I'd still like to know if it is unique.

Comment: For dimension $n=2$ and radius $r=1$ you have that $a(n)=\pi r^2=\pi$ so the kernel is $$\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\dfrac{1-|x|^2}{|x-y|^2}$$Now let $x=\rho e^{i\theta},y=e^{it}\in\partial D(0,1)$. After simplifications the kernel is :$$\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\dfrac{1-\rho^2}{1+\rho^2-2\rho \cos(\theta-t)}$$ which is the known Poisson Kernel on the unit disk of $\mathbb R^2$. 
The Poisson Kernel provides the solution for the above differential equation, which solution is unique. So there are not many "poisson kernels" it's just this one. Also, in the notes check the page 12 to see the formula I've written.

Comment: The constant on the left of the formula is used for normalization, so that the integral of the Poisson Kernel is $1$.